# How can I implement iTunes 11 "pop under" user interface element which shows additional information about album tracks

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I have been thing about how to achieve the really nice way iTunes 11 displays additional information about albums in a  (for lack of a better term) "pop under",

[image: iTunes 11 interface]

To make things simple let's limit ourselves to implementing this using a tableview with a single column.

A simple way would be to use a view-based table view and when the user selects a row insert a new view into the data source below the current selected view. By drawing an inner shadow in the view we can make it look like it is placed underneath.

This would look reasonably good, I'm not sure how to draw the triangular tab because it appears to straddle both views.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Nope. I gave up. Never really figured out how it was done. Might be worth investing with Xcode UI debugger